# Updating textbox while another thread is running WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

Here is the architecture of my app. I have a Perl script that is called using the method below on click of a button.

```
        ProcessStartInfo psStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("perl.exe");
        psStartInfo.Arguments = paramStr;
        psStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        psStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;


        ps.StartInfo = psStartInfo;
        ps.Start();
        string os = ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

The above code executes successfully. There is a text file which is generated using the Perl script I fired in the above mentioned code. I have to read that file and show everything in that in my WPF textbox. That Perl file is updated after every 5 to 10 secs. I use the below mentioned code to read the file and show it in my textbox.

```
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

     private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtExecLog.Text = "";

        if (File.Exists("C:\\FlashAuto\\Execution_Logs\\log.txt"))
        {
            File.Copy("C:\\FlashAuto\\Execution_Logs\\log.txt", "C:\\FlashAuto\\Temp\\log.txt", true);
            TextReader readLogs = new StreamReader("C:\\FlashAuto\\Temp\\log.txt");
            string line = readLogs.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                txtExecLog.Text += "\n" + line;
                line = readLogs.ReadLine();
                txtExecLog.ScrollToEnd();
            }

            CountLines = txtExecLog.LineCount - 1;
            readLogs.Close();
            // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
            txtExecLog.ScrollToEnd();
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            readLogs.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            txtExecLog.Text += "log file not found at: "+DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Here is the problem:

Reading and writing to the textbox is successfully done but there is a huge chunk of memory that is eaten up by my app. If I disable the logging, memory usage is optimal.

Comment: What is the size of the generated file? This (loading the file into memory, the same in the text box) is probably causing higher memory consumption.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the original log file to a temp log file, you can open the original log file for reading only and update the textbox by reading from original log file only? May be you can also use a FileSystemWatcher component for watching the updates to the original log file and keep updating the textbox...

Comment: You could try and read the file with `File.ReadLines` (.NET 4), and then replace the `while` loop with a foreach loop, to add each line to a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Try to enclose `TextReader readLogs = ...` into `using(...) { }` statement to guarantee `IDisposable.Dispose()` will be called

Comment: @Vijay: Just wanted to know if writing from a Perl script and reading from WPF at the same time will not cause any issues (File access issues)?

Comment: @Rohan No, there will not be any issues as long as the reading is done in the same format (text/binary) as was the format used while writing, irrespective of the languages used.